# Rails validation callback just once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I'm trying to figure out how can I validate a model just once.

Here is the situation:

It's about a library management

```
class Loan < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :book_id, :check_in, :check_out, :member_id

  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :member

  validates :member_id, :presence => true
  validates :book_id, :presence => true

  validate :returned_book, :on => :update


  def returned_book
    self.book.update_attributes! quantity: self.book.quantity + 1
    self.book.update_attributes! borrowed_count: self.book.borrowed_count - 1
  end

end
```

What i would like to do, is when i put a `check_out` date (i'm returning a book):

- Increment the `quantity` of the book
- Decrement the `borrowed_count` of the book

But just once, not every time I update the record or change the `check_out` date

*Im my code here, every time I save (update) the record the validation runs...*

Comment: This smells like premature optimization.  You should start out computing the book attributes on the fly.  Counters are notoriously hard to get right.  Think about setting and clearing and setting the dates again.  Whatever scheme you come up with ought to track that, and the counter updates ought to look atomic, which requires explicit locking.

Comment: Yeah... A friend told me to reorganize my schema again without the counter columns. I'll try. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 1):

Validations should be used to validate things, not modify state. A callback would be more appropriate in this case. Maybe something like:

```
attr_accessor :quantities_adjusted

before_save :update_quantities

def update_quantities
  if changed_attributes.keys.include?('check_out') && !quantities_adjusted
    self.book.quantity += 1
    self.book.borrowed_count -= 1
    self.quantities_adjusted = true
  end
end
```

Comment: Almost!! Thanks for the explanation, but there is one thing...

When I change the `check_out` date the callback `update_quantities` runs again and I dont want it, because it's already returned no matter the date

Comment: I just took a WAG at what you're after. This should get you off in the right direction, you may need to adjust for your specific use case...